# How can I get metadata for newly minted tokens?

Tags: spl-token, metadata, spl-associated-token-account, spl

I'm trying to fetch metadata for newly minted tokens (SPL, not NFTs) and unable to get a lot of data apart from decimals, mint_authority etc, I'd like to get the Name, Picture of the token along with other general information.

What is my best source to get this data?

(Preferably in Python BUT if JS gets the job done, we can move over)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i assume you have the mint address if you can already get the decimal.
To get what you need (name, image...) you have to fetch metadata with metaplex.

```
import { Metaplex } from '@metaplex-foundation/js'
```

and then :

```
const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection) 
const nftMetadata = await metaplex.nfts()
    .findByMint({ mintAddress: new PublicKey(....) })
```

Comment: Yes, I do have the mint address.

Thank you for sharing, I'm going to try it!

Comment: if this replies to your question properly, please accept the answer :)